# ERROR: (gcloud.firebase.test.android.run) 'Pixel' is not a valid model

Tags: gcloud, firebase-test-lab

I tried to launch FireBase Test Lab from the command line but I got an error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.firebase.test.android.run) 'Pixel' is not a valid model
```

Here is how I tried to run the command:

```
gcloud firebase test android run \
--app app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk \
--test app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk \
--timeout 30m \
--results-bucket "locusmaps-android-sdk" \
--test-targets "com.locuslabs.android.sdk.TestUITest#testTapMapLabelRentalCarCenter" \
--use-orchestrator \
--device model=Pixel,version=27,locale=en_US,orientation=portrait \
--num-flaky-test-attempts 2 \
--environment-variables numShards=2,shardIndex=0
```

The only reference I could find to this error is [some source code](http://testcompany.info/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/firebase/test/exceptions.py) but no existing solution anyone has articulated.

How do I find the correct model number?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [gcloud firebase test android run documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firebase/test/android/run#--device) you can find a list of `MODEL_ID` with the following command:

```
gcloud firebase test android models list
```

So use `--device model=Pixel2` parameter instead of Pixel.